# How to style some posts on category page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

To be more specific: I have some posts which must look different than other posts on category page. Can't find any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tags` for exemple.

Add some specific tag to your post. then, use condition in your template to show whatever you want :

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
```

see wordpress doc [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) for tags

Keep in mind they are several other ways to do this !